# SimpleCurosrAdapter isn't work

Tags: android

I made a ListView to show the DB contents using SimpleCursorAdapter.

I tested many times and find out the initialization of SimpleCursorAdapter part is the problem.
(I saw the DB contents with following Toast message.)

The layout, and ids are perfectly match with xml files too...

Could you tell me what could be the problem? (Can the 'deprecated' make a problem?)

```
private void populateListViewFromDB() 
{
    Cursor cursor = dbAdapter.getAllRows();
    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
            {dbAdapter.KEY_DATE, dbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY, dbAdapter.KEY_COST,  
                 dbAdapter.KEY_EXPLANATION};
    int[] toViewIds = new int[]
            {R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3, R.id.textView4};
    /*
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = 
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,                               // Context
                    R.layout.cash_expense_list_layout,  // Row layout template
                    cursor,                             // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                    fromFieldNames,                     // DB Column names
                    toViewIds                           // View IDs to put information in
                    );

    //Set the adapter for the listView
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter); 
    */
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    // move to the next item each time
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        // get string and column index from cursor
        String date = cursor
                .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_DATE));
        String category = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_CATEGORY));
        String explanation = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_EXPLANATION));
        int cost = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbAdapter.KEY_COST));

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Date: " + date + "\n" + "Category: " + category + " Cost : " + cost,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Below is the logcat

```
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): Process: com.example.money, PID: 2730
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.money/com.example.money.CashAnalysis}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:172)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:120)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:52)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:78)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at com.example.money.CashAnalysis.populateListViewFromDB(CashAnalysis.java:35)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at com.example.money.CashAnalysis.onCreate(CashAnalysis.java:19)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): ... 11 more
```

Comment: @Selvin i don't think your sarcasm will change anything,  the guy seems to be waiting for an concrete answer,  not for a hint where to follow,  in other words: he wants a fish,  not a fishing rod

Comment: if he wants a fish then he should go to the marketplace, because he has know nothing about fishing ... `SimpleCurosrAdapter isn't work` is not valid question on SO ...

Comment: What is the error in logcat... show logcat.

Comment: Sorry..Some of the questions that I read in stackOverflow was the problem of cursor.close(). I will dig more before questioning in next time

Comment: do you have in the logcat something related to Cursor.close() ?

Comment: Yap.. You were right.  I thought that I already have id column so it was not matter, but the real problem was the name of primary key. **It should be _id not the id**...Thank you all guys to give me some comments about this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, deprecated is not causing this problem.

This error clearly tells you exactly what the issue is - your database does not contain a column called `_id`, but this column is required

```
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

This line points you to the exact line of your codebase that caused the above exception

```
11-18 15:34:24.405: E/AndroidRuntime(2730): at com.example.money.CashAnalysis.populateListViewFromDB(CashAnalysis.java:35)
```

For more on why this column is needed, see [this Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#DisplayResults), which includes this note:

> Note: To back a ListView with a Cursor, the cursor must contain a
>   column named _ID. Because of this, the query shown previously
>   retrieves the _ID column for the "words" table, even though the
>   ListView doesn't display it. This restriction also explains why most
>   providers have a _ID column for each of their tables.